# 10000 rows - selecting according to where clause - performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a database table with 10000 rows in it and I'd like to select a few thousand items using something like the following:

`SELECT id FROM models WHERE category_id = 2`

EDIT: The `id` column is the primary index of the table. Also, the table has another index on `category_id`.

My question is what would be the impact on performance? Would the query run slow? Should I consider splitting my `models` table into separate tables (one table for each category)?

Comment: Should I consider splitting my models table into separate tables (one table for each category)?   ---  No.  Never split tables based on the data in them like this.  If you have to search for something across all models, you'll need to run a seperate query against each model table (and hope you don't miss one)

Answer (score 3):

This is what database engines are designed for. Just make sure you have an index on the column that you're using in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get the 100 records

```
SELECT id FROM models WHERE category_id = 2 LIMT 100
```

Also you can create index on that column to get the fast retrival of the result

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `category_id ` (`category_id `)
```

**EDIT:-**

If you have index created on your columns then you dont have to worry about the performance, database engines are smart enough to take care of the performance.

> My question is what would be the impact on performance? Would the
>   query run slow? Should I consider splitting my models table into
>   separate tables

No you dont have to split your tables as that would not help you in gaining performance

Comment: The id column is the index of the models table.

Comment: @MantasD.Šimkūnas:- You can create index on the category_id

Comment: I also have an index on the category_id column

Comment: @MantasD.Šimkūnas:- Then you have what you want. However if you want to fetch only few rows then you can use LIMIT and rest of the performance efficiency your database engine will take care!

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly new to SQL however I would first index the column

Answer (score 0):

I agree with R.T.'s solution. In addition I can recommend you the link below :

https://indexanalysis.codeplex.com/

download the sql code. It's a stored procedure that helps me a lot when I want to analyze the impact of the indexes or what status they have in my database.

Please check.